# Relation does not exist when running rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have this in my `group_spec.rb` file:

```
describe Group do
  it { should have_many(:users) }
end
```

and this in my user_spec.rb file:

```
describe User do
  it { should belong_to(:group) }
end
```

When I run the tests, I get:

```
Failure/Error: it { should have_many(:users) }
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
PGError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist

   LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                           ^
   :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                ORDER BY a.attnum
```

In my group.rb file I have:

```
has_many :users
```

And in my users.rb file I have:

```
belongs_to :group
```

I feel like I'm missing something that should be obvious.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

John

Comment: Try running `rake db:migrate:reset db:test:prepare` to make sure the test database is up-to-date. If it doesn't work, please post your migrations and models.

Comment: That did the trick!  I had tried rake db:drop db:create db:migrate. . . why did that not work?  Does that not cover the test database?  If you make your comment an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't. Unless you set `RAILS_ENV=test` or use a Rake task that specifically targets the test DB (as `db:test:prepare` does), the migrations will run against the development DB.

Comment: Please see possible answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19804714/446267

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Thanks for your note here. I was hitting this (irritating) issue. A simple run of `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate` was a solve for me. For another route, using the rake command instead - `rake spec ....` will properly prepare the test db before execution.

Answer (score 29):

Had this same problem and used the solution in the comment from cuvius. Posting here so that people don't miss it!

Run: `RAKE_ENV=test rake db:migrate:reset db:test:prepare` to set up your test database.

Comment: If you're getting this error because you removed a table, make sure you've removed your fixtures .yml file.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately **rake db:test:prepare** is deprecated in **rails 4+** so it's not best solution now.
I guess that in your user factory class written as **User**. The problem occurs because factories loads before migrations done.
So to solve this:
Change in your factory class name from

```
factory :user, class: User do
  # ...
end
```

to

```
factory :user, class: 'User' do
  # ...
end
```