# PG undefinedtable error relation users does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0, rake-task

I saw this question up before, but only for rspec. I haven't created test yet because it's too advanced for me but one day soon i will! :P

I get this error when I try to sign-up/login into my app. I used devise to create user and also *omniauth2* to sign-in with *google*.

**this is the error**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

I tried `rake db:migrate`, but it already is created: in schema table users exist. Has anyone got this error before?

**database.yml**

config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: tt_intraweb_development
  pool: 5
  username: my_username
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: tt_intraweb_test
  pool: 5
  username: my_username
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: tt_intraweb_production
  pool: 5
  username: my_username
  password:
```

Comment: Has any answer been helpful?

Comment: Not for me, having the same error and none of the answers have been helpful.

Comment: @GustavoLobo have you a propermigration set up?

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, sorry for that. `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate` worked for me.

Answer (score 141):

At first, you shall detach all connections out of database. By default you use the *development* environment. Then try to reset database with the following:

```
rake db:reset
```

> The rake db:reset task will drop the database and set it up again. This is functionally equivalent to rake db:drop db:setup.
>
> This is not the same as running all the migrations. It will only use the
>   contents of the current schema.rb file. If a migration can't be rolled back,
>   rake db:reset may not help you. To find out more about dumping the schema see
>   Schema Dumping and You section. [*Rails Docs*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#resetting-the-database)

If the trick doesn't help, drop the database, then re-create it again, migrate data, and if you have seeds, sow the database:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

or in short way (since 3.2):

```
rake db:migrate:reset db:seed
```

Since `db:migrate:reset` implies drop, create and migrate the db. Because the default environment for `rake` is *development*, in case if you see the exception in spec tests, you should re-create db for the *test* environment as follows:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

or with just loading the migrated scheme:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load
```

In most cases the test database is being sowed during the test procedures, so `db:seed` task action isn't required to be passed. Otherwise, you shall to prepare the database (this is deprecated in *Rails 4*):

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

and then (if it is actually required):

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:seed
```

On newer versions of Rails the error **ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError** may be risen, so just prepend the tasks with a database environment set task: *db:environment:set*:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:environment:set db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Comment: for me - RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load works, thanks for answer. Great

Comment: `rake db:test:prepare` does the job.

Comment: Thank you Mr. you just save my life. I try to drop, create, migrate, setup but not any of those commands works until I try you command `rake db:reset`. The magic happens man!

Comment: I accidentally dropped my PG tables and got this error when attempting to migrate.  changing/altering migration and schema files have always been an anxiety for me. For me, I deleted a table and for some reason, PG still recognized it in the schema.  I ran `rails db:reset` just to drop and create everything locally and it realigned everything.

Comment: For me, I am using Rails version 7, and ```rails db:reset``` worked!

Answer (score 23):

I encountered this error, and upon my research, found out that one of the reasons for **PG undefinedtable error relation users does not exist** error is:

This error is a migration error. You may have created new model with some database attributes. After creating model you have to migrate attributes to your rails app schema.

If you are using local machine, for development, you can use command

```
rake db:migrate
```

If you're using heroku

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Excellent! For rails 5 you must use 'heroku run rails db:migrate'

Comment: This worked for me. I needed to run `rake db:migrate`. Thanks.

Comment: I also faced this when I made a change to my Table name from `article` to `blog_article` instead of changing the model class name to `BlogArticle` I still left the name of the model class as `Article`

Answer (score 16):

Your test database is not ready for rspec.

Prepare your test database for rspec to fix this error

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake test:prepare
```

It will drop, create and add migrations to your test database

In case rake task is aborted with message like 'PG::Error: ERROR:  database "[your_db_test]" is being accessed by other users' execute this one

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 14):

I was getting this error as well when running rspec:

```
 Failure/Error: it { expect(subject.priority_list).to eq [nil] * 9 }
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "priorities" does not exist
   LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"priorities"'::regclass
 ...
```

It was resolved for me after I ran

```
rake db:test:prepare
rake db:test:load
```

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar error. The root of my error was that I had a reference to a Rails model in my factories.rb file. So it caused a load error issue. The fix was to wrap the reference in a block or `{}` so that it delays running it.

Here was the BROKEN code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    guid User.new.send(:new_token)
  end
end
```

And it was erroring because `User` was not defined when factories.rb was being loaded. I wrapped the `User.new` call in a block and it solved the issue:

Fixed code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    guid { User.new.send(:new_token) }
  end
end
```

Note: probably not best practice to need to call your model like this, but it was a solution to DRY up my code.

Comment: Can anyone please explain why it's "probably not best practice to need to call your model"?  I agree with the DRY benefits...what are the drawbacks?  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

This is often caused by a bug in ActiveAdmin. Here's how to get around the bug:

If you're using ActiveAdmin, whichever table PG says doesn't exist, comment out the contents of that ActiveAdmin rb file.

For example, for this case `PGError: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist`, comment out the entire contents of `app/admin/users.rb`, then uncomment after you've done your migrations.

Comment: you can also comment all admin areas at routes:
# ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

Answer (score 6):

That issue for me was being caused by Factory Girl rails. I would recommend for those using it to rename the specs/factories folder to specs/temp and attempting

RAILS_ENV=your_environment bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace

If it passes, then you just found what was causing it. A quick dig through the Factory Girl Rails gem github repo helped me identify the issue.

The factories were failing because I was trying to instantiate a Model that didn't exist upon running! Code sample below:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :billing_product, class: 'Billing::Product' do
    name            Faker::Cat.name
    product_type    'fuel'
    active          true
    payment_options [Billing::PaymentOption.new(term: 1, payment_term: 1)]
  end
end
```

Encapsulating the Array in a block (adding {}) did the fix for me. Note that payment_options can take more than one payment option in the example...

```
payment_options {[Billing::PaymentOption.new(term: 1, payment_term: 1)]}
```

Refer to the [Dynamic Attributes part of the Factory Girl Rails docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#dynamic-attributes) for more info.

Don't forget to rename your factories folder back!

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem and then I discovered the following solution.

Make sure You have entered all of the following credentials in the database.yml file and they are correct:

```
development:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: my_database
 host: localhost
 port: 5432
 pool: 5
 username: postgres
 password: xyz

test:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: my_test_database
 host: localhost
 port: 5432
 pool: 5
 username: postgres
 password: xyz
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem after I deleted the users table. solutions was changing

```
change_table(:users)
```

to

```
create_table(:users)
```

Answer (score 3):

**`::Migration[5.0]`** was missing in migrations.
instead of throwing **syntax error** it throws

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation roles does not exists

after wasting hours I finally figured out that migration is missing **`::Migration[5.0]`**.

**Erroneous Migration:**

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord # <---- Pay attention
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :code, limit: 2
      t.boolean :is_active, default: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Fixed and Correct Migration**

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :code, limit: 2
      t.boolean :is_active, default: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This could be a bug with rails and might help someone, instead of struggling and wondering.

Comment: yes!!! I don't think it's a bug though it is a common issue for rails 5. I think rails purposely did this [Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord.](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/issues/444)

Answer (score 2):

The most probable cause is that your rake is using different environment from database.yml than your webserver.

Comment: Hi, how is this something I can be sure of? is there command I can put in the terminal?

Comment: and how you are starting your webserver?

Comment: I am just running locally right now using rails s in the terminal

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error while trying to run tests using rspec.

I followed  Малъ Скрылевъ's steps but still ended up short. The final step I needed to do was load my schema into my test database using:

`RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load`

After that the problem went away and I could move on to the next bug. Hopefully that gives you some insight.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the Admin folder and run rake again.

Answer (score 2):

(I know this is old, but for future googlers)

Are you using `devise`? I know specifically `omniauthable` is a problem, but maybe others as well. It doesn't have to be `devise` though. Generically the solution is to comment out the offending model, class, whatever, and un-comment any sections the errors ask for.

For me, what was happening is that `devise` is reading the `User` model to see what you have as arguments for `devise` (the class method
i.e. `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable #etc`)

But, it will read the whole file and if this isn't a new project it might get tripped up by other class methods relying on other things (in my case it was the `friendly_id` gem, and then an `alias_method`

The answer was to comment out the `User` model except for the `devise` lines(s) * and `rake db:schema:load` should run fine.

- otherwise I got this error:

  ArgumentError: Mapping omniauth_callbacks on a resource that is not omniauthable
  Please add `devise :omniauthable` to the `User` model

Answer (score 2):

If you get this error while migrating, make sure your model name is plural

e,g.

```rb
add_column :images, :url, :string
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it turned out to be caused by [Grape API](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape). I noticed in the stack trace that the routes file was being read during the migration.

In routes.rb the Grape api is mounted

```
mount API::Base => '/'
```

And in the API were references to the missing model. So, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1861486/179412) I put it in a block that detects whether its being run by the server or during the migration.

```
unless ( File.basename($0) == "rake" && ARGV.include?("db:migrate") )
    mount API::Base => '/'
end
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the following error and doing a lookup into all my application code for `type_zones` I was unable to find it. I also looked at the db and it was updated.

Turns out it was a file under fixtures `/test/fixtures/type_zones.yml` that was causing the trouble.

```
ERROR["test_should_get_new", UsersControllerTest, 0.47265757399145514]
test_should_get_new#UsersControllerTest (0.47s)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "type_zones" does not exist
    LINE 1: DELETE FROM "type_zones"
                        ^
    : DELETE FROM "type_zones"
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is still having this problem, in my case, it was my factory in FactoryGirl that was triggering this error.

I was trying to add reference via '.new' or '.create'.

Answer (score 0):

So having the same problem just now. Remember to have only one model in each migration. That solved it for me.

[I came across the answer here.](https://github.com/globalize/globalize/issues/136)

Answer (score 0):

I was catching the Error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
```

It turned out to be a super easy fix. I had copied files over from an older version of the project and forgot to nest them inside of a "migrate" folder. When I did that it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

it usually can happen when you use **wrong type of association**  between models, check for dependency destroy and has_many associations, for example:

**wrong way that can cause this trouble:**

article.rb

```
 has_many :subcategories, through: :categories, dependent: :destroy
```

subcategory.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
```

**right way:**

article.rb

```
 has_many :subcategories, through: :categories, dependent: :destroy
```

subcategory.rb

```
declare association with categories here not articles (belongs_to / has_many_and_belongs_to)
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting the migration file in your commit can cause this issue. When pushed on heroku for e.g. `rails db:migrate` will obviously not work. Be sure that the migration file defining the undefined table have been committed.

Answer (score 0):

My case was also related to `FactoryGirl`/`FactoryBot` and I just had to change the definition. Replacing the constant by a string.

My env:

```
Rails 5.2.6
factory_bot 4.8.2
```

From this:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, class: Admin::User do
    ...
  end
end
```

To this:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, class: 'Admin::User' do
    ...
  end
end
```

Which is something recommended by [Getting Started - Specifying the class explicitly](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#specifying-the-class-explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run test.rake script and encountered the same issue. Spent a lot of time trying to understand what's going on. Eventually, it get fixed after I **renamed** the file.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had to comment out *2* `ActiveAdmin` files. Here were my steps:

1. Initial error/stacktrace (note we're using `Solr` on this project):

   `` ⇒  rkdbm
   java version "1.7.0_25"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
   => Solr is already running
   rake aborted!
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "discussions" does not exist
   LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"discussions"'::regclass
                                       ^
   :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                    pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
             FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
               ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
            WHERE a.attrelid = '"discussions"'::regclass
              AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
            ORDER BY a.attnum
   /Users/matthewcampbell/Sites/code/stack-builders/AchieveX/app/admin/users.rb:25:in block in <top (required)>'
   /Users/matthewcampbell/Sites/code/stack-builders/AchieveX/app/admin/users.rb:1:in'
   /Users/matthewcampbell/Sites/code/stack-builders/AchieveX/config/routes.rb:3:in block in <top (required)>'
   /Users/matthewcampbell/Sites/code/stack-builders/AchieveX/config/routes.rb:1:in'
   /Users/matthewcampbell/Sites/code/stack-builders/AchieveX/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace) ``

I commented out the `app/admin/discussions.rb` file per [Arcolye's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20322552/2517033) and tried to migrate my database again.

Same error.

I looked at the stacktrace a bit more closely, and noticed that in fact `app/admin/users.rb:25` was throwing the exception - and sure enough, that file has a dependency on my `discussions` table (via executing `Discussion.all`).

Finally, commenting out the contents of `users.rb` allowed me to finally migrate my database successfully.

FYI: there's a discussion [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2342) in `ActiveAdmin` about whether that gem should load the database when required.