# Rake Aborted: Pins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I am trying to learn Ruby, thus far have been breezing through for a few days but finally really stuck on this error message:

```
$ rake db:migrate
==CreatePins: migrating =====
--create_table<:pins>
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "pins" already exists: CREATE TABLE "pins" <"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "description" varchar<255>, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime> C:/users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/##########_create_pins.rb:3:in 'change'
c:in 'migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
<See full trace by running task with --trace>
```

I've tried rake db:rollback, rake db:rollback STEP=2, going into individual files and eliminating anything that has any resemblance to pins/pins table. Perhaps I did something wrong with git push or push heroku?? Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have data that you don't to loose? You could try to drop and-create the database if not.

Comment: How do you do that? I have data I'd rather not lose though..

Comment: On my localhost/3000 I get this message: Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.     But it doesn't solve the issue when I run it...

Comment: show this migration `##########_create_pins.rb`

Comment: reconstruct the table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097558/pg-undefinedtable-error-relation-users-does-not-exist/19804714#19804714

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 
 rake db:reset 
i hope its work for you. If it not work than you have 2 migration file for same table pins delete anyone and again run
 rake db:reset

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you ,I work it out by adding "drop_table:pins" at my create_pins.rb