# Rails Project and cannot get db:migrate with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Hey I recently started working on a Ruby on Rails project. I cloned the directory and when I try to run rake db:migrate or rake db:setup or rake assets:precompile I get this:

```
tests-macbook-pro-5:supersmart macgill$ bundle exec rake --trace RAILS_ENV=production assets:precompile
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/fog-1.3.1/lib/fog/core/service.rb:187:in `validate_options'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/fog-1.3.1/lib/fog/core/service.rb:58:in `new'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/fog-1.3.1/lib/fog/storage.rb:13:in `new'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:83:in `eager_load_fog'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:96:in `fog_credentials='
/Users/macgill/Rails/2/supersmart/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:118:in `configure'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
/Users/macgill/Rails/2/supersmart/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/macgill/Rails/2/supersmart/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
```

I also get this when I try the same in the development ENV:

```
tests-macbook-pro-5:supersmart macgill$ bundle exec rake --trace RAILS_ENV=development assets:precompile
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using #scope without passing a callable object is deprecated. For example `scope :red, where(color: 'red')` should be changed to `scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }`. There are numerous gotchas in the former usage and it makes the implementation more complicated and buggy. (If you prefer, you can just define a class method named `self.red`.). (called from <class:User> at /Users/macgill/Rails/2/supersmart/app/models/user.rb:39)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using #scope without passing a callable object is deprecated. For example `scope :red, where(color: 'red')` should be changed to `scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }`. There are numerous gotchas in the former usage and it makes the implementation more complicated and buggy. (If you prefer, you can just define a class method named `self.red`.). (called from <class:User> at /Users/macgill/Rails/2/supersmart/app/models/user.rb:40)
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

rake aborted!
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `async_exec'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_no_cache'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:138:in `block in exec_query'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `block in log'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:915:in `column_definitions'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:174:in `columns'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:114:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `yield'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `columns'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:208:in `columns'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:217:in `columns_hash'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:37:in `descends_from_active_record?'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:43:in `finder_needs_type_condition?'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:164:in `relation'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:28:in `all'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/base.rb:67:in `all'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:2:in `any?'
/Users/macgill/Rails/2/supersmart/factories/factories.rb:52:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `run'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:7:in `define'
/Users/macgill/Rails/2/supersmart/factories/factories.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl_rails-4.4.1/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:21:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/macgill/Rails/2/supersmart/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/macgill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
```

This is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: supersmart_dev
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: supersmart_test_env
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: supersmart_prod
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  host: localhost
```

Comment: can you show your `database.yml` file

Comment: it looks like your production settings do not include `aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key`,  You will need to define them for production

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19804714/3367343 and let me know if that resolves the problem with your development environment.

Answer (score 1):

You have your error because you don't have production config set for `fog` gem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  For some reason, Factory Girl was providing some data that the database did not like.  I commented out the code below from my factories.rb file and the problem was fixed.

```
factory :student do
  sequence(:first_name)  { |n| "Person_first #{n}" }
  sequence(:last_name)  { |n| "Person_last #{n}" }
  sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@risd.edu"}
end
```

Thanks for all your help!