# rails with server heroku and devise giving error , even after rake db:migrate

Tags: heroku, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

hi i am currently doing a blog in which will be used later and i have added devise into it , having finished in my local machine i uploaded it in the heroku and then i got a very fantastic error that i cant seem to fix, i also tried to change it in the production and doing this into the codes

```
this is for the config/environment/production
```

config.consider_all_requests_local       = true #false

to see what kind of error it give and this is what i got

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::RegistrationsController#new

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist LINE 5: WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass ^ : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped ORDER BY a.attnum

Extracted source (around line #592):
590    def exec_no_cache(sql, name, binds)
591     log(sql, name, binds) { @connection.async_exec(sql, []) }
592     end
593    
594
595
```

any help will do , as i have tried and did the

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

and i dont know what to do next

this is my gems

```
 gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 gem 'turbolinks'
 gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
 gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
 gem 'devise'
 gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
 gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
 gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
 gem 'ckeditor'

 group :production, :staging do
   gem "pg"
 end

 group :development, :test do
   gem 'byebug'
   gem 'sqlite3'
   gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
   gem 'spring'
 end
```

any help would really be appreciated and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found out the answer here: [PG undefinedtable error relation users does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097558/pg-undefinedtable-error-relation-users-does-not-exist)

the problem was i needed to run this code

```
 heroku run rake db:reset
```

and that did help me acces the database and now it is working fine