# Heroku Deployment failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I'm trying to deploy my app for the first time in heroku and I'm encountering a weird bug. When I try to run heroku rake db:migrate, i see this error :

> rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later
>   migrations canceled:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "companies" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" bigserial primary key, "admin" boolean DEFAULT 'f', "admin_c" boolean DEFAULT 'f', "color" character varying, "initial" character varying, "name" character varying, "surname" character varying, "pseudo" character varying, "step" integer, "company_id" bigint, "email" character varying DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password" character varying DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" character varying, "reset_password_sent_at" timestamp, "remember_created_at" timestamp, "sign_in_count" integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, "current_sign_in_at" timestamp, "last_sign_in_at" timestamp, "current_sign_in_ip" character varying, "last_sign_in_ip" character varying, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_7682a3bdfe"
FOREIGN KEY ("company_id")
  REFERENCES "companies" ("id")
)
```

I have verified a thousand times my migrations files Users & Companies but nothing seems bad. So I really don't know what to do. I also try all the database reset etc..
Like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097558/pg-undefinedtable-error-relation-users-does-not-exist?rq=1/) for example. But nothing is working for me. Anyone have seen this before ?? I'm really desperate at this point.

PS: And I also remove made the pg and sql3 changes.

So I give you my code if it can be useful to discover the problem

Company_model :

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, dependent: :destroy
end
```

User_model :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :company, optional: true

  has_many :users_group, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :users_group
  has_many :users_post, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, through: :users_post
  has_many :tasks_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tasks, through: :tasks_users

  has_many :requests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groupes_admin, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy

end
```

Company migration :

```
class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :ref

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Devise migration :

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.boolean :admin, default: false
      t.boolean :admin_c, default: false
      t.string :color
      t.string :initial
      t.string :name
      t.string :surname
      t.string :pseudo
      t.integer :step

      t.references :company, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.boolean :admin, default: false
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
  end
end
```

Schema :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170727071936) do

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "content"
    t.boolean "done"
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "ref"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "groupes_admins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_groupes_admins_on_group_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_groupes_admins_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "cat"
    t.boolean "main"
    t.boolean "perso"
    t.integer "effectif", default: 0
    t.integer "elm", default: 0
    t.integer "elm_d", default: 0
    t.integer "date_cat"
    t.integer "date_id"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.integer "company_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_groups_on_company_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.boolean "attached"
    t.integer "attached_cat"
    t.integer "attached_id"
    t.boolean "done"
    t.datetime "done_at"
    t.integer "done_cat"
    t.integer "donner_id"
    t.datetime "upd_at"
    t.integer "upd_cat"
    t.integer "updater_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.date "deadline"
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_posts_on_group_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.datetime "validate_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_requests_on_group_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_requests_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "subtasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.boolean "finished"
    t.datetime "done_at"
    t.integer "done_id"
    t.integer "assign_id"
    t.integer "task_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["task_id"], name: "index_subtasks_on_task_id"
  end

  create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.boolean "done"
    t.integer "doner_id"
    t.datetime "done_at"
    t.boolean "assigned"
    t.integer "elm", default: 0
    t.integer "elm_d", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_group_id"
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_post_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "tasks_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "task_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["task_id"], name: "index_tasks_users_on_task_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_tasks_users_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.boolean "admin_c", default: false
    t.string "color"
    t.string "initial"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "surname"
    t.string "pseudo"
    t.integer "step"
    t.integer "company_id"
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_users_on_company_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "users_groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_users_groups_on_group_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_users_groups_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users_posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_users_posts_on_post_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_users_posts_on_user_id"
  end

end
```

Comment: Same for me on heroku, I had to change host

Comment: two questions. is your `companies` migration before your `users` migration? and have you tried `rake db:schema:load` ?

Comment: thanks for your comment @m. simon borg, I was not sure about that point. I made templates to start with devise implemented. And it's the first time that I have a other model before. I change the order of the migration files, and I ran db:schema:load as you said. And now it's much better. Thanks for your advices. Good continuation

Comment: Great! I just put it in an official answer. If you felt like it helped you solve your problem please accept it

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that you're trying to create a reference to `companies` on the `users` table but the `companies` table doesn't yet exist. Try making sure the order of your migrations is such that `companies` is created before `users`. You can also try just loading the schema all at once rather than migrating one at a time, with `heroku run rake db:schema:load`.

DISCLAIMER: `rake db:schema:load` will wipe all of your data. It is best used for setting up a new database. Never run it against a production database that already contains critical data. Once you have data you will need to do incremental migrations.

Answer (score -1):

Create the database first with `rake db:create`.

Comment: I also try but is rendering me this error 

DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.

Comment: You do not need to create the database with Heroku. The commands `rake db:create`, `rake db:drop`, `rake db:reset` do not work on the Heroku platform